# Torque Setting Of A Compression Nut

Tags: maintenance

Could somebody please help me as I am struggling to find the answer.
I have searched the internet but cannot find anything specific to my bike,apart from a manual which does not have that much information.
I purchased a second hand Boardman URB 8:9 hybrid bike. It's not the current model, but one from a couple of years ago.
It came packaged in a box, so the usual pedals, handlebars etc, needed to be refitted.
When I came to putting the handlebars back on, I noticed the compression plug/nut inside the steerer tube is loose. With the forks being made of carbon I am worried about tightening this nut without knowing the recommended torque.

Answer (score 4):

The steerer-tube plug or bung has two functions:

1. Provide a backstop for tightening the stack;
2. Resist the crushing force on the steerer tube from the stem pinching it.

So the plug needs to be tightened just enough to serve the first function (for which some friction paste may help); this will naturally put it in a position to serve the second function.

It's also difficult to torque down hard on the plug, as there's nothing except friction against the steerer tube to hold the body in place as you tighten the bolt.

Comment: I've recently replaced the plug on my bike. The note in the packaging says the recommended torque is 5-6Nm.

Comment: I did a little searching on this, and couldn't find any consistent guidance on torque for plugs; in any case, it seems that the limit should be set by the fork, not the plug.